# How to write output per builder into separate log files in Packer?

Tags: packer, logging

I have a few packer templates which have several builders - up to 5 per template. This makes it very easy to provision all the resources necessary in a pipeline -- however by default packer writes all the output in a single stream. Yes, it separates builders by colour which makes it a bit easier to see what's going on, but it is nevertheless very difficult to find where a particular build failed.

I would like to know what would be a good way to split the packer output per builder into a separate file.

Note :

- I **do not** want to lose paralellism
- I **do** accept that some post-processing of the log is necessary

Packer has a `-machine-readable` flag which writes things like :

```
1564995900,,ui,message,    admin-ami: Instance ID: i-04ef2474a070403ad
1564995900,,ui,say,==> admin-ami: Waiting for instance (i-04ef2474a070403ad) to become ready...
```

which one could parse.

Comment: Could you check whether there is a related  issue on https://github.com/hashicorp/packer?

Comment: I agree this would be a useful feature in Packer.  Surprised it's not implemented right now.  I know how to split the output afterwards using grep on the colour headers, but no simple way to do this without a feature request.  It seems an easy feature to code.  I'll take a look.